# What is the data size of Hilton Software's WingX Pro 7 app and all of its databases?

Tags: cockpit, aeronautical-charts, electronics

What is the data size of the WingX Pro 7 installation files and databases including the app itself and the VFR Sectional, IFR Low Enroute, IFR High Enroute, and the full "All Charts(IFR)" databases?

I've noticed that the databases for different aviation apps have different sizes. What is the total storage for WingX Pro7 if you select the option to download all of the following databases:

1. List item
2. VFR Sections
3. IFR Low Enroute
4. IFR High Enroute
5. All Charts (IFR) - USA

My understanding is that WingX Pro7 uses higher compression than foreflight, leading to smaller database sizes, but I have been unable to find this information on their website, nor have their customer service responded to my email question.

UPDATE: I got my hands on a 16GB iPad Air and installed the latest version (July 2017) of WingX Pro 7 and downloaded all of the databases for the US including VFR and all IFR charts and plates for the Contiguous USA, plus terrain information. The only database I excluded was the High altitude IFR enroute charts. The total storage used by WingX Pro7 on the iPad is reported as 4.62GB.

2nd UPDATE: I finally got a response from HiltonSoftware on this question. They responded as follows:

```
Support  07/05/2017 at 2:25 PM
To: Devil07
Message body
WingX, fully loaded required 8GB
iOS may require at least 2GB free memory when all App are loaded
Space also has to be allowed for iOS

Support Team
```

Comment: The most you can get... Data sets are getting bigger all the time. Also depends how much distance you want to traverse, the father you go in one shot the more you need on hand.

Comment: We usually [avoid questions like this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the answers can change so quickly. I'd contact Hilton directly to ask, they'll know how much space is required for various features and which hardware is compatible.

Comment: Its just that I've spent several hours researching this online and the answers are all hedged (i.e. get the most memory and fastest processor you can afford) general answers. I figured this would be the best forum to ask specific question about modern aviation navigation tools, and how they are actually being implemented in the cockpit. I'm not asking for recommendations on what brand is best.

Comment: Example: When I bought my iPad 2 years ago when I started flying I got the 16GB mini. It was more than enough at the time. Now that I fly farther and Foreflight has started to include more data like their new maps, and more airport info than they once did I push the limits of storage just keeping all the charts I need for the northeast. i.e. get the most you can now and it will last you for a while, eventually you will need to upgrade.

Comment: I'm a software engineer, not a pilot, but I don't need to know diddly about flying to answer this one. Get as much as you can afford. You quite literally cannot buy enough storage today to satisfy your needs a few years down the road, so save yourself some future money and hassle and just buy it now.

Comment: I think that everyone uses the same data from the AeroNav charting office of the FAA and it is no longer rasterized but is in vector form. Compression differences wouldn’t be an issue. ForeFlight says that the app plus all the downloads for the 48 states takes 6 GB of storage space.  (Not including the new Jeppesen charts.) If you start adding manuals, logbooks... Then you would need more. Plus, once you start using it you”ll probably want to add a few more aviation apps as well. 16GB is probably the bare minimum required. The next size up (32GB) is adequate. 128 GB  will last you for a while.

Comment: @JScarry that is interesting. Do you know when FAA changed to vector form?  My comment about Hilton using more compression was based on article I read online dated 2014, so its very likely it has changed since then. If you can track down some source to confirm current WingX total database size, please answer question and collect the bounty! :)

Comment: @Devil07 It turns out that they are not exactly vector files but GeoTiff format. Previously they were scans of the paper version and now they are completely digital. I don’t recall exactly but it was not more than 2 years ago. The neat thing is that you can zoom in really far the text is still readable.

Comment: This is a question about modern aircraft navigation equipment as provided for in the "help center". This is equivalent to asking a question about a panel mounted VFR GPS. After being out of aviation for a few years I missed the transition to digital, and this is a legitimate question by a pilot directed to other pilots about navigation equipment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app itself only takes up about 15-20MB, according to the Google Play or iTunes app store, where as ForeFlight takes up 226MB (almost a quarter of a gigabyte) and Avare is less than 2MB and free. After downloading a good handful of charts, Avare is about 250MB. If you are very tight on space and running Android, you could try Avare. Otherwise if you need WingX Pro 7 or are on Apple, **5-6GB** is what you should have free if you plan to use all the charts. If you're buying a new tablet, try to go for a 32GB model to be safe and have plenty of room for other apps additionally, otherwise 16GB should also work.